# Adding a description/hint to your component props in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

i'm adding this new components to a project and I want to provide information about the specific prop, like a hint or acceptable values that can be passed to. Like when you press ctrl+space and it appears a description of the prop. Is there a way to do that in my component ?
I want to provide information that the component can only accept 'warning', 'success' and 'default' as type.

[image]

```js
<template>
  <v-chip
    :color="`state-${type}`"
    :outlined="outlined"
  >
    <slot />
  </v-chip>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    text: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'default', // but can accept 'success' and 'warning'
    },
    outlined: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Google **JSDoc**. Use it. Or switch to Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Although I dont know how to answer the whole question, you may try prop validators.

```
 // other props
    type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'default', 
        validator: (value) {
            const validValueList = ['default', 'success', 'warning'] 
            return validValueList.includes(value)
        }
    }
// more props
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30171826)